# Autofilter on one column for three dates

Tags: vba

I am new to Macro, I need help with the below code. I want to filter on one column for three dates provided by user. The below macro gives me blank result.

```
Sub newdate()
Dim today As Date, yesterday As Date, tomorrow As Date

    yesterday = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter yesterday date:", Type:=2))
    today = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter today date:", Type:=2))
    tomorrow = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter tomorrow date:", Type:=2))

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & yesterday
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & today
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & tomorrow
```

Comment: Changed title capitalization and one instead of once.  Formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

To filter by three dates, use an array for criteria instead. Try this.

```
yesterday = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter yesterday date:", Type:=2))
today = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter today date:", Type:=2))
tomorrow = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter tomorrow date:", Type:=2))
arrDates = Array(yesterday, today, tomorrow)

ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
  Criteria1:=arrDates, _
  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Btw do you need to ask the user for the dates? You can set today's date automatically via Date and use DateAdd to find yesterday or tomorrow.

```
yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
today = Date
tomorrow = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
arrDates = Array(yesterday, today, tomorrow)

ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=5, _
    Criteria1:=arrDates, _ 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```